# how to call variable defined in reactive function of shiny in other reactive function

Tags: r, shiny

I have following `server.r` file in Shiny

```
 enterdata <- reactive({
     a <- "Hello"
     b <- data.frame()

 })
```

How would I call variable `a` in other reactive function. I have dataframe as weell in `enterdata`,but I want only `a` to be called in other function

```
 getdata <- reactive({

    sum <- paste(enterdata()$a,"Neil")

 })
```

Is the above right way to do it?

Comment: The reactive's value is what is returned from your reactive, here it is the last expression, so only the data.frame. Have a look at `reactiveValues` to store several named objects.

Comment: You can create the variable outside the `reactive` function and internally update/modify using `<<-`. Later you can use it outside.

Answer (score 2):

You should treat `reactive` as a `function`. Therefore if you want to return more then one value put it for example in a list, like here:

```
enterdata <- reactive({
    a <- "Hello"
    b <- data.frame()

    list(a = a, b = b)

 })
```

Later you can just treat it as list:

```
getdata <- reactive({
    sum <- paste(enterdata()$a,"Neil")
 })
```